# Add new list, string and restructure to existing JSON array with jq

Tags: json, string, concatenation, jq

I have this input.json

```
{
   "list": [
      {
         "something1": "aaaa",
         "status": {
            "totalItems": 2,
            "Items": [
               {
                  "city": "santa",
                  "state": "VA",
                  "adress": "1 avenue"
               },
               {
                  "city": "manhatan",
                  "state": "NY",
                  "adress": "1 drive"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "something1": "bbbb",
         "status": {
            "totalItems": 0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to add list and append some text between the value and have output like this:

```
{
   "Newlist": [
      {
         "name": "NewName.aaaa",
         "HaveItem": "Yes",
         "Data": [
            "santa is a city of VA with address 1 avenue",
            "manhatan is a city of NY with address 1 drive"
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "NewName.bbbb",
         "HaveItem": "No"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have tried using jq '.list | map({name: .something1, HaveItem: (if .status.totalItems != 0  then "Yes" else "No" end), Data: (if .status.totalItems != 0 then .status.Items else "NULL" end) })' but i dont know how to add string between value.

Answer (score 0):

One way to join two strings is with `+`, e.g. instead of

```
name: .something1
```

you would write

```
name: ("NewName." + .something1)
```

Taking your query as a starting point, the next step would be to wrap everything in an object with `Newlist` as the key:

```
{ Newlist:
    .list
    | map({name: ("NewName." + .something1),
           HaveItem:
             (if .status.totalItems != 0 
              then "Yes" 
              else "No" end),
           Data: 
             (if .status.totalItems != 0
              then .status.Items
              else "NULL" end)
    } ) }
```

You should be able to tweak this to produce the final result you want.

Comment: how to convert the map to list with jq?